# Why when my modal opens, the background is darkened?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have an example of my modal code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal).

I can not figure out which part of the code makes the background darkened when the modal is open, please give me any hint, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look at your `.modal` css!

```
.modal {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
padding-top: 100px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* <-- this is the culprit */
}
```

The `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);` is the reason the background is greyed out. If you deactivate that one, or override it with a rgba that is lighter the darkened effect will be removed (for example, to remove the grey effect and reset it with a fully transparent black, set `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)` ).

`rgba(0,0,0,0.4)` means black (`rgb(0,0,0)`) but with only 40% opacity (the `0,4` at the end).

The reason that the modal shows a dark overlay is because the `background-color` is set to a dark color and the `width` and the `height` of the modal is set to `100%`. Thus, the background of the modal is effectively the entire screen high and wide, and has the color that is set in your inline CSS. So whenever you activate the modal (by clicking the button), you show the fullscreen dark overlay.

Answer (score 1):

It is the div with a black colour and opacity what makes the effect, that is

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
```

This div is hidden by default (via `display: none`), and is shown by JavaScript when the user clicks the "Open modal" button.